# Найти обработчик событий в Windows

Tags: windows, .net

В проводнике  Windows пользователь выполняет переименование или удаление папки. Данное событие обрабатывается приложением и идёт обращение к исполняемому файлу (до окончания изменения имени папки или удаления её. Как найти то (библиотеку или что-то аналогичное), что содержит обработку данных событий?
П.С.
найти нужно, т.к. это мешает пользователям и работе других программ. Автор для реализации данного решения скорее всего использовал dotnet и csharp

Comment: Абсолютно ничего не понятно. За эти операции в ОС отвечает ядро, а не какой-то экзешник. Как это может кому-то мешать? 

Прочитайте про проблему микроскопа и молотка:https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy

Comment: Это когда в проводнике, что-ли переименование/удаление?

Comment: Да. Пользователь в проводнике переименовывает папку или удаляет её. Перед этим событием идёт команда на запуск приложения. Нужно найти, что содержит обработчик этих событий

Comment: Называется "file notification"  http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher больше информации - вбить в поисковике "file notification c#"